# Transaction timeout when publishing page

Tags: 2013-sp1, publishing, sdl-tridion, deployer

When publishing one particular Page we are getting below error:

> "ERROR ParallelDestinationWorker - Timeout of 90000 ms exceeded for
>   transaction tcm:0-xxx:xxxx"

I have below configuration in tridion deployer for below files:
1) cd_deployer_conf.xml

```
<HTTPSReceiver MaxSize="4294967295" Location="E:\tridion\incoming\abcd.com" InProcessDeploy="true"/>
```

2) Web.config

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
```

3) cd_transport_conf.xml

```
<Senders SendTimeout="90000">
```

Can I change the value of `SendTimeout` to more than 90000 ms?

Comment: Yes, try increasing the SendTimeout on the Senders element in cd_transport_conf.xml. The default is 60s.

e.g. to increase it to 900s:

<Senders SendTimeout="900000">

Answer (score 1):

You can increase timeouts for sure. 90 seconds for deploy in real case scenarios can be really little. But be vary of increasing it too much. This can as a result have transactions which execute for too long without breaking to false state. And one more note. **Be sure to increase timeouts on CM side also**. This means that you should increase pooling interval for transport service. Because if you do not do so, transport service will mark transaction as failed while it's still being deployed since transport time outed, but not deployed
 So to sum up, these timeouts on CM and CD side should be in sync.

Answer (score 0):

This Settings can be increased. but before that there are couple of questions:
1. as this is happening only for 1 page, is this page content is too big compared to other pages?
2. is this error started happening from begining or started occurring after some changes in infrastructure side?

Comment: Yes, this is happening only for 1 page and that content is too big on this page. this page was working fine, content team added multiple components to the list and thats when publishing started failing.

Comment: then for sure time out settings need to be increased. or as an workaround if possible try to create dynamic components instead of adding all components in 1 single page. so that components will be rendered dynamically on page load.